# How can i monitor Openstack with prometheus and grafana

Tags: openstack, prometheus, grafana

I installed openstack with devstack on Ubuntu 20 and installed prometheus and grafana with node exporter and it showed on grafana no issues, but how to monitor openstack components Nova.... There is a Openstack Exporter in grafana but its show as empty

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't use devstack but my own openstack deployment method. Can you verify if prometheus successfully scrapes openstack metrics? Is there something like an openstack-exporter service running? I was able to manually install prometheus and then pull the docker image as described [here](https://github.com/openstack-exporter/openstack-exporter). After configuring grafana to use that new datasource I can create my own dashboards containing the metrics.

Comment: I used "snap install --channel stable golang-openstack-exporter"but don't know how to proceed from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write that you already have prometheus running so I will not go into details about that. The description in the [docs](https://github.com/openstack-exporter/openstack-exporter) are kind of straight forward. It offers different installation methods (docker/podman container or via snap). Both options to start the exporter worked for me (podman container and snap).

### Configure the exporter

```
1. Create a clouds.yaml    
root@control01:~# cat clouds.yaml 
clouds:
  admin:
    region_name: "RegionOne"
    identity_api_version: 3
    identity_interface: "internal"
    auth:
      username: admin
      password: ****
      project_name: ADMIN
      project_domain_name: Default
      user_domain_name: Default
      auth_url: 'https://control.example.com:5000/v3'

2. Start openstack-exporter (I recommend the legacy mode first)
root@control01:~# podman run -v "$HOME/clouds.yaml":/etc/openstack/clouds.yaml -it -p 9180:9180 ghcr.io/openstack-exporter/openstack-exporter:latest admin
ts=2023-10-07T12:23:21.616Z caller=main.go:64 level=info msg="Build context" build_context="(go=go1.18.10, platform=linux/amd64, user=, date=, tags=unknown)"
ts=2023-10-07T12:23:21.616Z caller=main.go:85 level=info msg="openstack exporter started in legacy mode"
ts=2023-10-07T12:23:21.617Z caller=tls_config.go:274 level=info msg="Listening on" address=[::]:9180
ts=2023-10-07T12:23:21.617Z caller=tls_config.go:277 level=info msg="TLS is disabled." http2=false address=[::]:9180

2a. Using the snap you should be able to just start the exporter instance from the command line:
$ ./openstack-exporter --os-client-config /etc/openstack/clouds.yaml myregion

3. Verify
root@control01:~# curl http://localhost:9180/metrics
# HELP openstack_cinder_agent_state agent_state
# TYPE openstack_cinder_agent_state counter
openstack_cinder_agent_state{adminState="enabled",disabledReason="",hostname="control",service="cinder-backup",uuid="94ecf3be-864e-a2a0-dd93-7e9f8e38adf5",zone="nova"} 0
openstack_cinder_agent_state{adminState="enabled",disabledReason="",hostname="control",service="cinder-scheduler",uuid="c4cda40e-9d17-f960-fa84-cc3897ddda9f",zone="nova"} 1
[and many more]

4. Add openstack-exporter to prometheus (just an excerpt of the new job)
root@control01:~# tail -5 /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
  - job_name: openstack
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9180']
    scrape_interval: 120s
    scrape_timeout: 120s
```

In my case I have prometheus server running on the control node as well (just a test environment), that's why I have the target defined as "localhost".
Now you can use any of those metrics to create your own grafana dashboards to visualize the metrics with graphs.

### Configure Grafana

You need a running grafana instance where you have permissions to add dashboards, I won't go into those details.
You can [import the dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/9701-openstack-dashboard/) you referred to, I imported the json file. During the import you're asked for the json file and the prometheus data source.
As soon as the exporter is started and prometheus has collected its metrics you should see graphs in the imported dashboard:
[image: Openstack exporter dashboard]

Comment: Thank you, i was finally able to install openstack exporter, but still the final goal to make this https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/9701-openstack-dashboard/  work still not showing any data

Comment: I added the grafana part to my answer.

Comment: With your help and instructions i was able to identify my problem. Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

In the case of wallaby version openstack, some graphs are not displayed. e.g. overall memory usage, overall cpu cores usage, local storage, etc. The reason for this is that the hypervisor values were removed from the 2.88 nova API.

https://docs.openstack.org/nova/wallaby/reference/api-microversion-history.html#maximum-in-wallaby

The reason for this is, presumably, that the nova api is not burdened by these queries. This was consolidated and moved to the placement API, so it can be requested from this metric even in openstack-exporter version 1.6.0 (but also older).

Some information about the placement API for hypervisors

https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/nova-specs/specs/wallaby/implemented/modernize-os-hypervisors-api.html

Placement metrics available from Openstack exporter:

> openstack_placement_resource_allocation_ratio{hostname="nova-a-01.cloud",resourcetype="DISK_GB"} 1
> openstack_placement_resource_allocation_ratio{hostname="nova-a-01.cloud",resourcetype="MEMORY_MB"} 1
> openstack_placement_resource_allocation_ratio{hostname="nova-a-01.cloud",resourcetype="VCPU"} 16
> openstack_placement_resource_allocation_ratio{hostname="nova-a-02.cloud",resourcetype="DISK_GB"} 1
> openstack_placement_resource_allocation_ratio{hostname="nova-a-02.cloud",resourcetype="MEMORY_MB"} 1
> openstack_placement_resource_allocation_ratio{hostname="nova-a-02.cloud",resourcetype="VCPU"} 16
>
> openstack_placement_resource_reserved{hostname="nova-a-01.cloud",resourcetype="DISK_GB"} 0
> openstack_placement_resource_reserved{hostname="nova-a-01.cloud",resourcetype="MEMORY_MB"} 4096
> openstack_placement_resource_reserved{hostname="nova-a-01.cloud",resourcetype="VCPU"} 0
> openstack_placement_resource_reserved{hostname="nova-a-02.cloud",resourcetype="DISK_GB"} 0
> openstack_placement_resource_reserved{hostname="nova-a-02.cloud",resourcetype="MEMORY_MB"} 4096
> openstack_placement_resource_reserved{hostname="nova-a-02.cloud",resourcetype="VCPU"} 0
>
> openstack_placement_resource_total{hostname="nova-a-01.cloud",resourcetype="DISK_GB"} 1314
> openstack_placement_resource_total{hostname="nova-a-01.cloud",resourcetype="MEMORY_MB"} 385046
> openstack_placement_resource_total{hostname="nova-a-01.cloud",resourcetype="VCPU"} 64
> openstack_placement_resource_total{hostname="nova-a-02.cloud",resourcetype="DISK_GB"} 1314
> openstack_placement_resource_total{hostname="nova-a-02.cloud",resourcetype="MEMORY_MB"} 385046
> openstack_placement_resource_total{hostname="nova-a-02.cloud",resourcetype="VCPU"} 64
>
> openstack_placement_resource_usage{hostname="nova-a-01.cloud",resourcetype="DISK_GB"} 0
> openstack_placement_resource_usage{hostname="nova-a-01.cloud",resourcetype="MEMORY_MB"} 256
> openstack_placement_resource_usage{hostname="nova-a-01.cloud",resourcetype="VCPU"} 1
> openstack_placement_resource_usage{hostname="nova-a-02.cloud",resourcetype="DISK_GB"} 0
> openstack_placement_resource_usage{hostname="nova-a-02.cloud",resourcetype="MEMORY_MB"} 0
> openstack_placement_resource_usage{hostname="nova-a-02.cloud",resourcetype="VCPU"} 0
>
> openstack_placement_up 1

in this case,

sum(openstack_placement_resource_usage)

should be used instead of

sum(openstack_nova_memory_used_bytes)